# Only the_excerpt seems to return anything

Tags: php, wordpress

When producing a front page of a website and trying to grab five excerpts from the wordpress database it produces the excerpt, no problem, but it completely ignores my the_title, get_the_id and the_date:

```
foreach( $post as $posts) : setup_postdata($posts);
  echo "<hr><h1>" . the_title( false, false, false ) . "</h1>";
  echo the_excerpt( ) . "<br />";
  echo "<a href='./index.php?p=" . get_the_ID( ) . "'><font color='white'>Read More...</font></a><br />";
  echo "Published on: " . the_date( false, false, false, false );
endforeach;
```

Which produces the output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNkxh.png

And as such, the 'Read More...' is directed to './index.php?p='

I have defined the get_posts statement as follows:

```
$args = array(
   'posts_per_page'   => 5,
   'numberposts'      => 5,
   'offset'           => 0,
   'category'         => $c,
   'order_by'         => 'post_date',
   'order'            => 'DESC',
   'include'          => '',
   'exclude'          => '',
   'meta_key'         => '',
   'meta_value'       => '',
   'post_type'        => 'post',
   'post_mime_type'   => '',
   'post_parent'      => '',
   'post_status'      => 'publish',
   'suppress_filters' => true );

$post = get_posts( $args );
```

Any ideas on what went wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yep,you are right. Deleted my answer. But you got interesting problem. Try renaming $post to $mypost.

Comment: Same result as before. Seemed to work fine yesterday and the only thing that I've done since then is remove categories and deleted some of the testing posts that I had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies with `setup_postdata` function.

Quote from [setup_postdata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) Codex Page:

> Important: You must make use the global $post variable to pass the
>   post details into this function, otherwise functions like the_title()
>   don't work properly...

Example from that Codex page:

```
   global $post;

   // Assign your post details to $post (& not any other variable name!!!!)
   $post = $post_object;

   setup_postdata( $post );
   ...
```

So try renaming `$post` to `$mypost` and then use exact `$post` variable in the `setup_postdata()` like this:

```
foreach( $mypost as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
```

Comment: Not if you use the_title( false, false, false ) and likewise for the_date (with an extra false), because that just returns the value for use. And even if that was the case, it would still show up on the screen elsewhere without any formatting.